# ArcGIS: Selecting features from a grid layer which are on the edge of another feature by location

Tags: arcmap, vector-grid, select-by-location, borders

I have two layers which come from the same data source. The first one is a vector grid layer which contains 1km x 1km features and looks like this:

[image: Grid Layer]

The second one is the grid layer dissolved into Sub-Bains, which i.e. looks like this:

[image: Sub-Basin]

I need to select all the features from layer one which touch the borderline of each Sub-Basin of layer two from within the Sub-Basin. For example of this Sub-Basin:

[image: Select]

This has to be done for multiple (1000) Sub-Basins, so selecting them manually would be too time consuming.
To include some context: I need to identify the feature with the biggest water outflow into another Sub-Basin and for that I need to export all the features which are on the inner edge of the basin.

Is there a tool or a way this can be done?

Comment: Google Modelbuilder and iterators

Comment: Also, please decide which software you're using, otherwise the question will be closed for need of focus.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your requirements but if your vector grid was a flow accumulation raster converted to its vector equivalent, then go back to the raster and use the Zonal statistics tool with your sub-basins dataset and select the statistic to be the MAX value and it will do the lot in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually easy. I only needed to choose the Relationship as "Boundaries_Touches" in the Select Layer by location tool and it would select all the the features on the edge of each sub-basin. Then export the data and dissolve the sub-basin ID and choose the statistic type "max" for the outflow.